# Using methods to change JComponents style

Tags: java, swing

I have this problem of using my method "changeStyle" to change the appearance of my JButtons. I made a method which will change the background, border, and Opacity of my JButton. I tried to make another method to shorten the first code but it return an error, "The method changeStyle() is undefined for the type JButton."

The code that I tried to shorten:

```
public void buttonChange(){
        rock.setBackground(defaultColor);
        rock.setBorder(defaultBorder);
        rock.setOpaque(false);
        paper.setBackground(defaultColor);
        paper.setBorder(defaultBorder);
        paper.setOpaque(false);
        scissor.setBackground(defaultColor);
        scissor.setBorder(defaultBorder);
        scissor.setOpaque(false);

            switch(main.playerChoice){
            case 1:
                rock.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                rock.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true));
                rock.setOpaque(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                paper.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                paper.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true));
                paper.setOpaque(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                scissor.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                scissor.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true));
                scissor.setOpaque(true);
                break;
            default:
                rock.setBackground(defaultColor);
                rock.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                rock.setOpaque(false);
                paper.setBackground(defaultColor);
                paper.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                paper.setOpaque(false);
                scissor.setBackground(defaultColor);
                scissor.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                scissor.setOpaque(false);
                break;
        }
    }
```

This is the function I make to shorten buttonChange:

```
package RPS;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class changeStyle extends JButton{
    public changeStyle(Color color, Border border, Boolean bol){
        setBackground(color);
        setBorder(border);
        setOpaque(bol);
    }
}
```

Whole Code:

```
package RPS;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import RPS.changeStyle;

public class main extends JFrame{

    private static String version = "V. 0.02";


    private JPanel contentPane;

    JPanel titlePane = new JPanel();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Rock Paper Scissor " + version);

    JSplitPane split1 = new JSplitPane();

    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");

    JSplitPane split2 = new JSplitPane();
    JSplitPane split3 = new JSplitPane();
    JSplitPane split4 = new JSplitPane();

    JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");
    JButton paper = new JButton("Paper");
    JButton scissor = new JButton("Scissor");

    static int playerChoice;
    static int computerChoice;

    static int playerScore;
    static int computerScore;

    static String finalScore;

    JLabel plScore = new JLabel("Player Score: " + playerScore);
    JLabel compScore = new JLabel("Computer Score: " + computerScore);
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");

    Color defaultColor = new JButton().getBackground();
    Border defaultBorder = new JButton().getBorder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                main frame = new main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }


    public main() {

        setTitle("Rock Paper Scissor " + version);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(titlePane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        titlePane.add(title);
        titlePane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

        add(split2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        split2.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        split2.setEnabled(false);
        split2.setTopComponent(plScore);
        split2.setBottomComponent(rock);
        split2.setDividerLocation(this.getHeight()/4);
        split2.setDividerSize(0);

        rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                main.playerChoice = 1;
                //System.out.println(main.playerChoice);
                buttonChange();
            }

        });

        plScore.setFont(plScore.getFont().deriveFont(12F));
        plScore.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

        add(split3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        split3.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        split3.setEnabled(false);
        split3.setTopComponent(compScore);
        split3.setBottomComponent(paper);
        split3.setDividerLocation(this.getHeight()/4);
        split3.setDividerSize(0);

        paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                main.playerChoice = 2;
                //System.out.println(main.playerChoice);
                buttonChange();
            }
        });

        compScore.setFont(compScore.getFont().deriveFont(12F));
        compScore.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));

        add(split4, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        split4.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        split4.setEnabled(false);
        split4.setTopComponent(reset);
        split4.setBottomComponent(scissor);
        split4.setDividerLocation(this.getHeight()/4);
        split4.setDividerSize(0);
        reset.setSize(25, 75);

        scissor.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                main.playerChoice = 3;
                //System.out.println(main.playerChoice);
                buttonChange();
            }
        });
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                finalScore = "";
                computerChoice = 0;
                playerChoice = 0;
                playerScore = 0;
                computerScore = 0;
                plScore.setText("Player Score: " + playerScore);
                plScore.setForeground(Color.black);
                compScore.setText("Computer Score: " + computerScore);
                compScore.setForeground(Color.black);
                buttonChange();
            }
        });

        //add(rock, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        split2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()/3 -6,0));
        //add(paper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        split3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()/3 -6,0));
        //add(scissor, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        split4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()/3 -6,0));

        add(split1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        split1.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        split1.setEnabled(false);
        split1.setDividerLocation(this.getWidth()/2);
        split1.setDividerSize(0);
        split1.setLeftComponent(play);
        split1.setRightComponent(exit);

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                int rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4);
                main.computerChoice = rand;
                //System.out.println(main.computerChoice);
                plScore.setForeground(Color.black);
                compScore.setForeground(Color.black);

                if(main.playerChoice == main.computerChoice){
                    finalScore = "Tie!";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, finalScore, "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else if(main.playerChoice == 1){
                    switch(main.computerChoice){
                    case 2:
                        finalScore = "Computer Wins!";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        finalScore = "Player Wins!";
                    }
                }else if(main.playerChoice == 2){
                    switch(main.computerChoice){
                    case 3:
                        finalScore = "Computer Wins!";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        finalScore = "Player Wins!";
                    }
                }else if(main.playerChoice == 3){
                    switch(main.computerChoice){
                    case 2:
                        finalScore = "Computer Wins!";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        finalScore = "Player Wins!";
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "You didn't choose!!!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                while(finalScore == "Player Wins!"){
                    playerScore+=1;
                    plScore.setText("Player Score: " + playerScore);
                    //INSERT POP UP 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, finalScore, "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    plScore.setForeground(Color.green);
                    finalScore = "";
                }
                while(finalScore == "Computer Wins!"){
                    computerScore+=1;
                    compScore.setText("Computer Score: " + computerScore);
                    //INSTERT POP UP
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, finalScore, "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    compScore.setForeground(Color.red);
                    finalScore = "";
                }

                main.playerChoice = 0;
            }
        });

    }

    public void buttonChange(){
        rock.setBackground(defaultColor);
        rock.setBorder(defaultBorder);
        rock.setOpaque(false);
        paper.setBackground(defaultColor);
        paper.setBorder(defaultBorder);
        paper.setOpaque(false);
        scissor.setBackground(defaultColor);
        scissor.setBorder(defaultBorder);
        scissor.setOpaque(false);

            switch(main.playerChoice){
            case 1:
                rock.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                rock.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true));
                rock.setOpaque(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                paper.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                paper.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true));
                paper.setOpaque(true);
                break;
            case 3:
                scissor.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                scissor.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true));
                scissor.setOpaque(true);
                break;
            default:
                rock.setBackground(defaultColor);
                rock.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                rock.setOpaque(false);
                paper.setBackground(defaultColor);
                paper.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                paper.setOpaque(false);
                scissor.setBackground(defaultColor);
                scissor.setBorder(defaultBorder);
                scissor.setOpaque(false);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Remove *all* the code which is irrelevant to the question. This will lo help you find the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], go through the [help], learn and post a valid [mcve] that follows the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `FirstLetterUpperCaseClass`, `firstLetterLowerCaseMethod` and `firstLetterLowerCaseVariables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending a class and adding functionality to doesn't make that functionality available to parent classes, only instances of the new class and it's children will have access to it, so when you use `JButton rock = new JButton("Rock");`, `rock` will NOT have the functionality of `changeStyle` (it's not an instance of `changeStyle`, so how can it?)

We could get into semantics about polymorphism and object casting, but let's just say you should be using

```
changeStyle rock = new changeStyle();
```

This will now allow you to call the `changeStyle` method.  Note, you will need to override the button's constructor if you wish to pass the text `String` to it when you create it

Java naming conventions would also suggest that class names should start with an uppercase character, so `changeStyle` should be `ChangeStyle`, while it might not seem like a big deal, it will make you code easier to read for others and for you to read other people's code, it's just a good habit to use